# Monitor labels appearing in displays on Linux Mint MATE

Tags: linux-mint, configuration, multi-monitor, monitors, mate-desktop

Monitor labels have started appearing in the upper left corner of each display as shown in this screenshot showing my 2 displays: external monitor and laptop.

[image]

The labels are always on top and do not respond to mouse actions.
They started appearing after I configured my dual display with monitor configuration tool as shown in the lower display of the screenshot.
It is very annoying as it access to menus on maximize windows.
I do not recall doing anything to enable this.

**What controls this or how to get rid of it?**

I am running Linux Mint 17/Qiana MATE which I keep reasonably up to date.

Comment: Have you closed the Monitor Preferences dialog?  If that didn't help, try clicking the Detect Monitors button.

Comment: @cjm I have tried both of those.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting/restarting X? Is the issue persistent across X restarts? Perhaps you should file a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I had 3 lingering `mate-display-properties` processes running.   Killing all of them fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Look for this process - `ps aux|grep display`

Locate its pid and kill it - `kill [:id]`